# EnvironmentError: Gmsh version must be >= 2.0

Tags: python, mesh, fipy

I am new to fipy, so excuse my ignorance if I ask something that should be obvious. But I fail to run an already existing (and working - on other machines) script, getting the `EnvironmentError: Gmsh version must be >= 2.0.` I may have missed something during the installation? Fipy manual is a bit vague about implementation of gmsh. It only provides the link to download file and that meshes can be generated by it, but it doesn't say WHERE gmsh should be installed (so I have my  `gmsh-3.0.3-Windows` in the default, i.e. in `Program Files (x86)`. Should it be installed in some particular directory, perhaps the same as fipy?
(I really apologise for a stupid question, but this is the case when if you know what question to ask, you already know the answer and don't need to ask at all.)

For completeness, I am running it on Windows 7, Python 2.7 from Anaconda distribution, fipy 3.1.3.

Comment: Launch the shortcut for Anaconda Prompt and type `conda list`, and then `pip list`, to check if you have gmsh.

Comment: See the answer below, the problem was with the exact location of the gmsh application. the .exe file needs to be among the scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. I made a desperate try - copied the `gmsh.exe` file into `..Anaconda2/Scripts/` and it did the job!

I think the fipy documentation should mention this. The chapter on mesh generation only says that you need gmsh, but does not specify that the application (.exe) has to be in the directory with python modules. But this is not quite intuitive (it is not a python file, not installed by pip, just a downloaded application from the web) and yet it is essential for running it.

Comment: Trying to repeat these steps in october 2021 I found that I also have to copy the gmsh dll file into the Anaconda/Scripts folder. It is in the /lib/ folder of the downloaded package. For me it is called gmsh-4.1.dll, might be different if your version is different. Also be adviced that as of 2021 there is a max version of gmsh (4.5).